# More than 100 opportunities should not be created by a user

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, triggercontext, trigggers

A user can not create more than 100 opportunities in a day..if the user tries to insert more than 100 opportunities error should come...
I am trying this way...

```
Trigger NotMoreThan1000Opportunities on Opportunity(before insert){ 
    Integer i = 1;
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){ 
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
        o.Id = opp.Id;
        o.ownerId = userInfo.getUserId();
        o.Name = 'Nizam';
        o.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
        o.CloseDate = System.today();

        if(i > 100){
            o.adderror('More than 1000 opps');
        }
        oppList.add(opp);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean 100 opportunities at a time?  But at a later time, the user can insert 100 opportunities again?

Comment: no a user cannot insert more than 100 opportunities in a day...

Comment: So modify your code something like this first get the number of opp. user trying to insert then get count of opp inserted today if `today inserted > 100 OR today inserted + inserting now > 100` show error to user;

Comment: Maybe you should ask what kind of company would forbid its sales people to create more than 100 opps. My company would love it when people would have so many opps! Or are users creating fake opps? Why would they do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
Trigger NotMoreThan100Opportunities on Opportunity(before insert){   
    Integer canCreate = 0;
    final Integer MAX_ALLOWED_TODAY = 4;

    List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate = today and CreatedById = :userInfo.getUserId()];

    /* Today current user already created these Opportunity/ies */
    Integer alreadyCreated = oppList.size();

    canCreate = (MAX_ALLOWED_TODAY < alreadyCreated)?0:(MAX_ALLOWED_TODAY - alreadyCreated);

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
       if(--canCreate < 0){
           opp.addError('You can create maximum ' + MAX_ALLOWED_TODAY + ' Opportunities today.');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **OwnerId =: userInfo.getUserId()** too in the query instead of CreatedById check.

```
Trigger NotMoreThan1000Opportunities on Opportunity(before insert)
{   
  //checking for opportunities created today by the logged in user
  List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate = today and CreatedById = :userInfo.getUserId()];

  for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){       
      if(oppList!=null && oppList.size>100){
          opp.adderror('More than 100 opps');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...An error is coming
Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Opportunity> at line 8 column 27

Comment: updated the code.  try

Comment: NOT WORKING...I can still make records more than 100.